# Importing csv and making spectra object with all information

Tags: r, data-import, spectra

I have a FTIR data set that has wavenumber in column 1 and all of the sample intensity / absorbance values in the other columns.
Looks like this

```
> FTIR<- read.csv(file="FTIR_20190328_test.csv", header = T, row.names = 1)
> head(FTIR)
               ID_3        ID_9       ID_21       ID_25      ID_29       ID_33
399.6748 0.05554183 0.072609851 0.039330115 0.055516636 0.03709701 0.055186592
400.1569 4.42064846 0.005875182 0.007921505 0.000000000 0.03182379 0.012444198
400.639  3.32078310 0.002113590 0.012585608 0.002157767 0.03158090 0.007927620
401.1211 2.22447073 0.000000000 0.017728826 0.004574567 0.03180063 0.004792073
401.6032 1.14204819 0.004404642 0.025178901 0.008065509 0.03402003 0.009207404
402.0854 0.06865115 0.012965923 0.034695270 0.012274070 0.03753230 0.019088973
```

I'm trying to create a Spectra object and use the Chemospec package in R. This is code I found in instructions.

```
# Get the data matrix
specs <- read.table(file = "FTIR_20190328_test.csv", sep = ",", header = T, row.names = 1)

# Set up the Spectra object
spectra <- list()
spectra$freq <- as.numeric(specs[,1])
spectra$data <- as.matrix(t(specs[,-1]))
dimnames(spectra$data) <- NULL
spectra$names <- names(specs[-1])
class(spectra) <- "Spectra"

# Go get group assignments & colors, to complete assembly of spectra

spectra <- .groupNcolor(spectra, gr.crit, gr.cols)
spectra$unit[1] <- freq.unit
spectra$unit[2] <- int.unit
spectra$desc <- descrip

if(chk) chkSpectra(spectra)

datafile <- paste(out.file, ".RData", sep = "")

R.utils::saveObject(spectra, file = datafile)

return(spectra)
```

I think I made the spectra object but it doesn't seem complete. When you use the test data set used in CRAN intro file (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ChemoSpec/vignettes/ChemoSpec.pdf) the spectra object is much more complete.
Theirs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB8PM.png)
Mine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca4Wz.png)

This block of code gives me an error:

```
spectra <- .groupNcolor(spectra, gr.crit, gr.cols)
spectra$unit[1] <- freq.unit
spectra$unit[2] <- int.unit
spectra$desc <- descrip
```

Here is error:

```
> spectra <- .groupNcolor(spectra, gr.crit, gr.cols)
Error in gr.cols[1] %in% builtInColors : object 'gr.cols' not found
> spectra$unit[1] <- freq.unit
Error: object 'freq.unit' not found
> spectra$unit[2] <- int.unit
Error: object 'int.unit' not found
> spectra$desc <- descrip
Error: object 'descrip' not found
```

How do I complete this spectra object so that it can be used in Chemospec. The directions don't explain what the matrix / spectra object should entail and the example doc of what their data would have looked like was not provided.

Ultimately, I am trying to visualize FTIR data but I can't even get the data in to mess with it.

Thank you in advance for any help.

I have tried to create spectra with the matrix2SpectraObject command but I'm not even 100% I'm entering the correct information in there.
I am literally just trying to get the data into R in the appropriate format to use Chemospec, which is apparently a powerful tool for FTIR visualization.

Comment: This isn't my field, but looking through the vignette it looks like you are supposed to provide the values for `freq.unit` (in the vignette it uses "ppm") `int.unit` ("peak intensity") and descrip ("Subspecies Study") yourself (ref p4). So does your example work if you specify e.g. `freq.unit <- "ppm"; int.unit <- "peak intensity"; descrip <- "Subspecies Study"` before running your code block?

Comment: @jared_mamrot
I tried to use their code:
matrix2SpectraObject(
  gr.crit = c("ID_"),
  gr.cols = c("auto"),
  freq.unit = "Wavelength",
  int.unit = "Absorbance intensity",
  descrip = "Treatment effects on necromass spectra",
  in.file = "FTIR_20190328_test.csv",
  out.file = "necro",
  chk = FALSE,
)
but nothing happens.... :(

Comment: Did you include the `ssp <-` part? I.e. `ssp <- matrix2SpectraObject( gr.crit = c("ID_"), gr.cols = c("auto"), freq.unit = "Wavelength", int.unit = "Absorbance intensity", descrip = "Treatment effects on necromass spectra", in.file = "FTIR_20190328_test.csv", out.file = "necro", chk = FALSE)` then do you get anything if you type `str(ssp)`?

Comment: @jared_mamrot is on track here, but if the OP saw nothing there might be something else going on.  If you don't assign the result, it should dump into the console, which should be obvious.

Comment: Didn't work for me.. I've tried everything I could think. Thank you both for your reply!
> ssp<-matrix2SpectraObject(
+   gr.crit = c("ID_"),
+   gr.cols = c("auto"),
+   freq.unit = "Wavelength",
+   int.unit = "Absorbance intensity",
+   descrip = "Treatment effects on necromass spectra",
+   in.file = "FTIR_test.csv",
+   out.file = "necro",
+   chk = FALSE,
+ )
Error in matrix2SpectraObject(gr.crit = c("ID_"), gr.cols = c("auto"),  : 
  could not find function "matrix2SpectraObject"
> str(ssp)
Error in str(ssp) : object 'ssp' not found

Comment: For future visitors, OP needed `sep = ","` as `ChemoSpec::matrix2SpectraObject` uses `read.table` under the hood for maximum flexibility.  Details are in `?matrix2SpectraObject`.